# Java error: Cannot be resolved to a variable

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I'm trying to create a minecraft plugin with Java, bukkit.

```
@EventHandler
public void onItemDrop(PlayerDropItemEvent e) {
    /*
     * Dropping items
     */
    Item item = e.getItemDrop();
    item.setMetadata("NODROP", new FixedMetadataValue(plugin, e.getPlayer()));
    if (!e.getPlayer().hasPermission("nodrop.drop")) {
        e.getItemDrop().remove();
        e.getPlayer().sendMessage(colorizeText(ChatColor.RED + getConfig().getString("drop-message")));
    }
}
```

The error I'm getting is 'plugin' on

```
    item.setMetadata("NODROP", new FixedMetadataValue(plugin, e.getPlayer()));
```

which is:

plugin cannot be resolved to a variable

Please help!

Comment: You didn't define `plugin` anywhere, so how should Java know what to use when you tell it to pass `plugin` to `FixedMetadataValue()`?

Comment: First think, what is the type of `plugin`? Then think, have you specified that in the method?

Comment: Well, it means you have no variable named "plugin", obviously enough...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what needs to happen is a line of code like this within the method body:

```
Plugin plugin = new Plugin();
```

Or you could declare `plugin` as an instance variable:

```
public class Foo  
{
    private Plugin plugin;  //initialize later  
    ...
    public void onItemDrop(PlayerDropItemEvent e) {  
     ...
   }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that @Woot4Moo's answer is correct. Quite frankly; it will throw up errors when you come to run your plugin.

The above error can be fixed in one of two ways:

**Change plugin to this**
If your EventListener is in the main plugin class (the one that extends `JavaPlugin`) then you can simply change the `plugin` section to `this`.
`item.setMetadata("NODROP", new FixedMetadataValue(this, e.getPlayer()));`

**Get an instance of the plugin**
If your EventListener is in another section of your plugin then when you declare the listener change it to `getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, new SomeEventListener(this)` and make a constructer that takes the plugin instance sent and stores it.

```
public SomeEventListener(JavaPlugin instance) {
    this.plugin = instance;
}
```

Then you can simply leave the item.setMetadata as it is.

Comment: OP's issue was not with the correct way to get the `JavaPlugin` class, it was a fundamental misunderstanding of how to allocate / assign objects.  So I would suggest that your response is actually the incorrect one as it does not apply in all such cases.

Comment: @Woot4Moo If the OP was to run this code: `item.setMetadata("NODROP", new FixedMetadataValue(new Plugin(), e.getPlayer()));` it would throw an error causing the plugin not to work.